# Guarantee that signal handler will be called when sigsuspend returns

Tags: c, signals

Suppose that I have the following signal handler set up for `SIGALRM`:

```
volatile sigatomic_t alarm_flag;

void alarm_handler(int signum)
{
    (void)signum;
    alarm_flag = 1;
}
```

Then suppose I've called `alarm` and then entered a section of code where `SIGALRM` is blocked but I'd like to synchronize with it.  That is, I want to use `sigsuspend` to wait for the alarm to expire:

```
sigfillset(&set);
sigdelset(&set, SIGALRM);
sigsuspend(&set);
some_other_command();
```

Is there any POSIX guarantee that `alarm_handler` will have been called by the time `some_other_command` is executed or do I need to  do the following?

```
sigsuspend(&set);
while ( !alarm_flag );
some_other_command();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the POSIX documentation for [`sigsuspend()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/functions/sigsuspend.html):

> If the action is to execute a signal-catching function, then `sigsuspend()` shall return after the signal-catching function returns, with the signal mask restored to the set that existed prior to the `sigsuspend()` call.

So yes, there is a guarantee. If you weren't blocking `SIGALARM` in the `sigsuspend()`, at least (and assuming the alarm wasn't handled before calling it, of course).

Comment: In the OP's example, it's not the `alrm_handler` which is the "signal-catching function" which is causing `sigsuspend` to return (since the `ALRM` signal was blocked in its `mask` argument). Yes, the question could've been more clear.